# exec is no use ,I do not know how to solve

Tags: docker, exec, containers, ibm-cloud

My IBM Bluemix container is running. If I run `cf ic exec -it my_container bash`, it shows me:

> Error response from daemon: Container nova-96e528bf-6eed-4973-a92b-47b705d0b60f

It is not running and if I run `cf ic attach my_container`, it shows me nothing and window is bad. Why?

Comment: How do you know the container is running? What does `cf ic ps -a -f "id=nova-96e528bf"` (or just run it through grep instead of a filter) show?

Comment: cf ic ps -a   It is show running.and I rebuid another container，and I can exec into the container ,but show me root@instance-002894a5:/# .after,when I Enter the command，it

Comment: cf ic ps -a   It is show running.and I rebuid another container，and I can exec into the container ,but show me root@instance-002894a5:/# .after,when I Enter the command，it show me panic:runtime error:slice bounds out of range,goroutine 15 [running]: bufio.<*reader>.fill<0*11216420> ......docker was not found